# Yukawa interaction and four fundamental forces

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, strong-force

What is the difference(or relation) between Yukawa interaction($\mu\bar{\psi}\phi\psi$) and the other four fundamental interactions(e.m., weak, strong and gravity)? Does it fall anywhere on the symmetry breaking scale starting from Big bang?
Edit:
How to understand Yukawa interaction with parallel to the other four forces? Now that Quantum Chromodynamics (QCD) is the theory that describes the interactions inside a nucleus, my understanding is: Yukawa theory was developed much before the advent of gauge theories to explain the nuclear interactions. So, is Yukawa theory redundant or obsolete? I know that Yukawa interaction now is used in Standard Model to describe the interaction between massless fermions and scalar Higgs boson.

Comment: Yukawa is not a gauge force, for a start.

Comment: I'm not sure what this question is asking for. A list of all the differences between a Yukawa interaction and a minimal gauge coupling would be *too broad*. Can you be more specific what you want to know?

Comment: I am trying to understand how Yukawa interaction differs from the other four forces. Slereah started by clearing that it is a non-gauge force; we use it in the Standard Model in the Spontaneous Symmetry Breaking. May be this is the best way to ask: can it be derived from the other four forces directly or as an approximation as it is not fundamental?

Comment: Please reopen this post for better answering